# Recreate Row Groups in SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

Is there a way to remove and then recreate row groups? We have a report that is believed to be "corrupt" (because we've upgraded from SSRS 2008 to R2). From what we've researched, recreating the row groups might fix it for us.

I've found these links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170712.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255263.aspx

but I can't seem to create groups without extra rows/columns being created that are not needed for the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long couple of weeks trying to solve the problem within the .rdl files, we opened a ticket with Microsoft.

A work-around was provided to us in that; We could remove a row from multiple groups by right clicking that row > Insert Row > Outside Group - Above.

This effectively creates a duplicate row outside of one of the groups. We then followed the steps above on the newly created row.In turn we created 4 duplicate rows (each in one less group then the previous row), and kept the last created row which wasn't in any groups!